# Siemens CT dose report/patient protocol PixelData

Tags: python, ocr, dicom, pydicom, simpleitk

I’m trying to extract dicom PixelData from Siemens’ dose report but it contains only zeros. With GE dose report I read the data without a trouble with pydicom or simpleITK. Any ideas why siemens report contains only zeros?

Thanks!

Came this far, but characters are a mess, I don't know what else to do.

```
import dicom 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f="patient-protocol.dcm"
ds=dicom.read(f)  
overlay_px_data = ds[0x6000, 0x3000].value  
rows = ds[0x6000, 0x0010].value  
cols=ds[0x6000, 0x0011].value

arr=np.fromstring(overlay_px_data, dtype="uint8")  
arr=np.unpackbits(arr)  
arr=np.reshape(arr, (rows, cols))

plt.imshow(arr, cmap="gray")  
plt.show()
```

[dose-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfF89.png)

Comment: Can you please provide sample code?

Comment: I will, but I did some digging around again and I suspect the dose info is an overlay under 60xx,3000 tag. Will try to play around some more and be back.

Answer (score 0):

```
i_overlay = 1
n_bits = 8


# On (60xx,3000) are stored ovelays.
# First is (6000,3000), second (6002,3000), third (6004,3000),
# and so on.
dicom_tag1 = 0x6000 + 0*i_overlay

overlay_raw = data[0x6000,0x3000].value

# On (60xx,0010) and (60xx,0011) is stored overlay size
rows = data[0x6000,0x0010].value # rows = 512
cols = data[0x6000,0x0011].value # cols = 512

decoded_linear = np.zeros(len(overlay_raw)*n_bits)

# Decoding data. Each bit is stored as array element
for i in range(1,len(overlay_raw)):
    for k in range (0,n_bits):
        byte_as_int = overlay_raw[i]
        decoded_linear[i*n_bits + k] = (byte_as_int >> k) & 0b1


overlay = np.reshape(decoded_linear,[rows,cols])

plt.imshow(overlay)
plt.show()
```

Found the solution for now. Edited a code a bit (removed ord()), a numpy decoding solution would be great/better.

[code source link](https://github.com/mjirik/lisa/wiki/Read-dicom-overlay-with-pydicom)